# Recyclerview does not inflate

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am working on creating recycler view.

I have 2 Activities.

Activity A contains recyclerview, and Activity B contains 2 edittext views.

I set the button in Activity B onClickListener so that the input data of edit texts pass to adapter. Those two input data of edittexts are binded in the object Arraylist. Passing data works by the way, but it does not inflate. I would like to know what I did wrong.

Activity A which contains recyclerview :

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    ArrayList<MainData> list = (ArrayList<MainData>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list");

    adapter = new MainAdapter(list);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Activity B which contains EditText Views :

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            LinearLayout itemView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        Intent intent = new Intent(upload.this, MainActivity.class);

            ArrayList<MainData> list = new ArrayList<MainData>();

            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_name);

            EditText edit_main = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_main);

            list.add(new MainData(edit.getText().toString(), edit_main.getText().toString()));

            intent.putExtra("list",list);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

MainData :

```
  public MainData(String tv_name, String tv_content) {
    this.tv_name = tv_name;
    this.tv_content = tv_content;
}
```

Adapter :

```
   private ArrayList<MainData> list;

 public MainAdapter(ArrayList<MainData> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MainAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, 
parent, false);

    CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}
  @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.tv_name.setText(list.get(position).getTv_name());
    holder.tv_content.setText(list.get(position).getTv_content());

    holder.itemView.setTag(position);

        @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != list ? list.size() : 0);
}
```

Recycler view xml file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/rv"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
   android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
   android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/black"
   android:scrollbars="vertical"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:text="move"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>
```

Comment: could you share your xml for recycler view

Comment: on it, 1 second

Comment: have u checked if your list contains data or not?

Comment: Make your MainData model class serializable because while transactions passing model class through intent we get the serializable data so you need to make your model class serializable.

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane Yes! Passing data works very well. everytime I try to create more than two recyclerview, it passes data only, but the number of recycler view stays 1.

Comment: @KhushParmar I have tried that, and it does not work.. :(

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane more than one recycler view, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try to change getItemCount methode to be just like below

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```